# Integration testing for elasticsearch 6.1.1 using ESIntegTestCase

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch

Not able to run the junit test case using ESIntegTestCase

```
@RunWith(com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class)
@ClusterScope(scope=SUITE, numDataNodes = 3)
public class SampleClassTest1 extends ESIntegTestCase{
....
}
```

Always get the following error

```
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread: Thread[id=16, name=Thread-1, state=RUNNABLE, group=TGRP-SampleClassTest]. Is this thread running under a class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner runner context? Add @RunWith(class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class) to your test class. Make sure your code accesses random contexts within @BeforeClass and @AfterClass boundary (for example, static test class initializers are not permitted to access random contexts).
```

Could someone please let me know how to move forward.
Thanks in advance.